# Is there a way to merge two branches interactively line by line in magit

Tags: magit, git

How can I merge two branches with magit interactively line by line. Important there is no conflict (well ONLY for git it isn't) but I still want to do this.

Comment: Well, you could revert the commit, rename the files you are interested in merging, then fetch files from the other commit you are merging with, then `M-x emerge-files` them. (See more on how emerge works [here](http://www.nongnu.org/emacsdoc-fr/manuel/emerge.html)), this is even more hardcore than `git reset --hard HEAD^1 && git difftool -t <call Emacs Ediff> HEAD^1 HEAD`. But neither of them would be my choice. I typically do the initial merge in whatever quick way possible and then ammend the rest of the changes after merge. I've not seen yet a comfortable diffing tool.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Press <kbd>M-x magit-status</kbd>
2. Press <kbd>m</kbd> in magit status
3. Activate the "No fast-forward" switch and do Merge but don't commit Action and press <kbd>m</kbd> again
4. Now your files are changed but not committed, so you can merge them with your last commit state when you press <kbd>e</kbd> above the changed files
   that will bring you ediff and you're able to review the changes

Hope this will help you out.